# Can I use completely different keywords in a long-tail without affecting my rank?

Tags: keywords, meta-tags, meta-description, meta-keywords, blackhat

The example:
I need to rank for `free x123456 templates` and `free y123456 themes`, but I don't want to use two different long-tails, so can I use it like this `free x123456 y123456 templates themes`, having the same effect?

Second question: How many long-tails keywords can I add?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. There is no limit. Just don't write crappy content or else your rankings will suffer.

Comment: The whole notion of focusing too much on keywords has long been dead. Years in fact. The so-called SEO crowd needs you to focus on the magic voodoo incarnations that only they can provide. Just make a site for users that they will love. Be natural. It will perform as it should. Keep in mind that there is a very real danger in performing in the SERPs artificially.

Comment: John Conde, You mean it doesn't matter if I mix the keywords or not?
_br_
closetnoc, I have changed my template this month and it got me more than 50% drop in traffic, the new template has no meta description nor keywords, so meta stuff is not that useless, as it may help search engine to know what the website is about and how it correlates to the content.

Comment: Your issues sounds like simple SEO. Keyword manipulation, with little exception, has gone by way of the do do. Any change such as templates, title tags, and what not can disrupt your traffic for a while while your sites page values are recalculated. Search is about semantics and not keywords and has been for a long time. Some signals can be made such as title tags and so on, but the real value is in the content itself. Also, this BS about the description meta-tag having no SEO is just plain bull! Terms found within it carries little weight, but the primary and secondary effects are huge!!

Comment: I never said content is less important, I just said that I'm talking about keywords. I don't ignore any factor in SEO, it doesn't matter how irrelevant people may say the factor is. It's a simple question: Mixing the longtail keywords will make a difference, turning things to the bad side, or it's the same thing as use them separately? Just that. Keywords and Description are still used, and they indeed make a big difference. I base myself on practical meanings, not guru theories. It's like saying PR is not important anymore, it may not be like it was years ago, but it still is important.

Comment: And as I said, it's long tail keywords, not single keywords. Make a google search and you'll see many recent articles saying how important long tails are.

Comment: I realize what the SEO experts say. The fact of the matter is that there are no long-tail keywords. Not really. Only the keywords you target in the signals you send. Other than than that, it is all about semantic links in how your site ranks for any term. The so-called long-tail keywords you seek will be within your content. I am trying to warn you that is it less about keywords these days and more about linguistics and semantics. Just a warning. It is a new ball game these days. I am saying be more natural. Keyword density and manipulation is as dead as a do do with very little exception.

Comment: I got what you mean, I know content is important, but I need these keywords because I hired a SEO company to optmize them, they created too many external articles with them, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The example: I need to rank for free x123456 templates and free y123456 themes, but I don't want to use two different long-tails, so can I use it like this free x123456 y123456 templates themes, having the same effect?

Yes as long as it makes sense and that the resulting keyword set occupies 2% to 5% of the total text count. Anything more than 5% and it could be spam to search engines. Anything less than 2% and it might be declared as unimportant.

I like the tool provided on http://textalyser.net because it tells you what ranking important chains of words are in, but that site does not load at this time of writing. The next site that is ok is:

http://tools.seobook.com/general/keyword-density/

On the second site, the keywords in a long-tail will be listed as "3 word phrases" and "2 word phrases".

> Second question: How many long-tails keywords can I add?

In a web page itself, as many as you like.

Using phrases in the URL can help, but don't get too carried away because tests at http://try.powermapper.com/demo will turn bad if any URL exceeds a total of 78 characters.

In the title tag, I'd use caution if I were you because any title tag over 65 characters might not work too well with Bing search engine, and any tag over about 80 characters might get truncated when shown in search engine results, and it might even be truncated in title bars of maximized web browser windows.

In the description meta-tag, use caution as well as you don't want the description too long.

Whatever you do, just make sure that if you use multiple phrases on one web page, that they all relate to the web page.

For example, if you were writing a website about apples, and you had a long phrase of "red golden delicious apples", you could have another one of "bright green apples", but don't mix those phrases on the same page with "heart shaped dog biscuits" because that doesn't relate.